# Returning query value in OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am learning OOP. My question is based on below code. Each time the value is returned in index.php using `$query_value->GetName()` or `$query_value->GetId()`.

Is it running the MySQL query each time because of `$query_value`?

**In Class.php**

```
  <?php
class OOP{
    public $name,$id,$password

    public function query(){
        /* Query Performed
           rowCount() = 1 */
           $this->name = returned row  value;
           $this->id =  returned row  value;
           $this->password= returned row  value;
           return $this; // [NOTE THIS ($this)]

    }
    public function GetName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function GetId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**In index.php**

```
 <?php
 $test=  new OOP();
 $query_value = $test->query();
 // now returning values
 echo $query_value->GetName();
 /// Some Html
 echo $query_value->GetId();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it running the mysql query each time?(because of $query_value)

No, it's not running the query each time. With this statement `$query_value = $test->query();`, you executed the query **once** and set the instance properties using `$this->name`, `$this->id` and `$this->password`.

And in these statements `$query_value->GetName();` and `$query_value->GetId();`, you're only accessing the getter methods of your `OOP` class to get the *name* and *id* values, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not querying every time since the initial query() function was already called when instantiating the $query_value variable. With the fact that you have an obejct as $test you shouldn't need an additional variable to echo out the value

```
$test = new OOP();
$test->query();

// echo out the values

echo $test->GetName();
echo $test->GetId();
```

Then you don't need to return $this in the query() function since $test is the object variable and already has these values set.

Answer (score 1):

No because you only call that function once. GetName and GetId are separate methods of that class.

But what I would do is call getter methods like this:

```
echo $test->GetName();
echo $test->GetId();
```

It's a bit easier to understand. And your query() method files these values. What you did is just assigned your class to a different variable.